# Sample Triangle Region from 2D Texture in Metal/Swift

Tags: swift, arkit, metal, core-image, texture2d

To the best of my knowledge, texture sampler functions only allow sampling of coordinate points as oppose to regions across the texture. I instead need to sample the triangle region to then extract average colour. Is there a mechanism to do this efficiently on metal?

I have also looked into CoreImages, but masking an entire image especially given the triangle region being small is not ideal. Reducing of the rectangle of best fit speeds things up but I would imagine going the Metal way would be much faster, especially given that I want to do this for many triangular regions. Would really appreciate guidance on this front.

Thanks an enormous amount!

Comment: I believe the answer is no, there is no multi-sampling that I know of. It would be nice if there was a kernel sampling function that allowed 2x2, 3x3, 5x5 sampling etc.

Comment: Assuming you have the coordinates of the triangle, you could do the texture sampling in a vertex shader (some coordinate lattice would be passed in as buffer) and then pass the color to a fragment function where you could use destination blending (i.e. dst_color, programmable blending) to get an average. Or another option would be to use a compute kernel where using threadgroup memory you could calculate an average. Both methods involve individual coordinate sampling, given that you need triangles it might not possible to get an accurate average with downsampling and then sampling.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answers! @Gary, can you elaborate more on your solutions. I do have a vertex/fragment shader setup that I can use to map the texture to the 3D structure but don't know how to extract the corresponding triangle regions on the texture surface. Also, how does threadgroup memory work? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: The standard way of dealing with getting an average of many pixels using the vertex & fragment pipeline is to downsample the image to a smaller resolution, so you'd lightly blur the image (gaussian 1 sigma say, or box blur), and then downsample the texture to a smaller size (half the width and height), and then do it again (blur & downsample) and again until you can do one texture read where it will now give you an average, like how a gaussian pyramid is made. But given that you have triangular regions this is difficult, so there are other ways to get around this..

Comment: One possible way would be to use a technique used to get histograms. You could on the cpu end create a buffer of all the texture coordinates and send it to the vertex shader (or create the coordinates in the vertex shader based on the triangles vertices uniform/buffer), you can do a tex read in the vertex shader and pass the color along.  You would draw MTLPrimitiveTypePoint (not triangles) and you would be drawing into a small square texture (4*4 or whatever), pointsize would be the size of the square texture. Then in the fragment shader use programmable blending to get the average color

Comment: But now that we have compute kernels using the vertex & fragment pipeline is probably not the best/fastest way, with a compute kernel you have complete control and because you have some threadgroup memory you can store values from different texture reads and then average them. There is no way around doing multiple texture reads (downsampling is the only thing that can reduce the number of samples). It's hard to know which would be the best way for you, it depends on your skillset

Comment: Using the vertex & fragment pipeline you could do multiple averages at a time, if you only needed one average then you could use say 4*4 texture set the vertex position to 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), pointsize to 4 etc. But if you needed multiple averages you could just make a bigger texture and change the vertex position for each different triangle. Look into gpu-based histogram generation using vertex texture reads, your basically just modifying that technique